# JS coding won't work on more than one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new at this and have been able to get my code to work on my first page but not on any others. I tried to do it as an exported js file but it wouldn't work so I added it as a  at the the bottom of my html page. Now it just isn't working except on that one page!
So this one works:

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-position: bottom;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
img.sixth {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 4em;  
}

h1.first {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66CCFF;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 position: static;
 margin: 30px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66FF66;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 1.5em;
}

img.first {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 2em;
   display: none;
}

img.second {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   display: none;
}

img.third {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   display: none;
}

img.fourth {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
   display: none;
}

img.fifth {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   display: none;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="densi.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\densi_home.css">
  <title> DENSI 2017 </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!--Navigation bar-->
 <div id="nav-placeholder">

 </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav1.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
 <!--Finish NavBar-->
 
 <!--Page Heading-->

 <div id='heading'>
  <h1 class='first' align='center'><big> DENSI 2017 </h1 class='first' align='center'></big>
 </div>
 
  <img class='sixth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\DEN.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="250px"
  border="1px"
  position="center"
  alt=""/>

<!--Section 1-->
<div class="parent">
   <h2 align='center'> What is it? </h2>
  <p align='center'> DENSI stands for Discovery Education Network Summer Institute. It is a week long residential professional development that helps educators learn, share and connect with other educators about good practice; integrating technology into the classroom and to give different perspectives on strategies to engage children. </p>
      <img class='second' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\DENSI.jpg" alt="DEN Group Photo"
   height="150px"
   width="270px"
   border="1px"
   style="float: left; margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 3em;"
   />
  <img class='third' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\densi logo.jpg" alt="Discovery Logo"
   height="250px"
   width="180px"
   border="1px"
   style="float: right; margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom: 1em;"
   />
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>

<!--Section 2-->

<div class="parent">
  <h2 align='center'> Where was it held? </h2>
  <p align='center'> DENSI this year was held in San Diego at the University of California San Diego. In previous years it has been held in Washington, Chicago and Montana. San Diego has been a beautiful setting for DENSI this year (although there was no air con... and the wifi was a struggle...); once we had adjusted to the heat and the time difference we were well on our way to starting our once in a lifetime professional development experience!</p>
    <img class='fourth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\15.jpg"
   height="250px"
   width="180px"
   border="1px"
   alt=""/>
  </div>

<!--Section 3-->

<div class="parent">
 <h2 class='third'align='center'> Who was there? </h2>
 <p class='third' align='center'> There were over 150 attendees at DENSI this year, several of which travelled from Egypt, England, UAE, Dubai, Haiti, Kuwait and China. Information on attendees can be found <span style="cursor:pointer"><a href="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1K_mloa69fSR0ij0E7u1pjG_RkCzLxMUTk7JlLd04J2Y/edit"
  target="_blank">here.</a> 
  <p class='fourth' align='center'>
  Over the course of the week we had networked with the majority and had connected with many.</p>
  <img class='first' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\Int1.jpg" alt="Internation Group Photo"
   height="180px"
   width="250px"
   border="1px"
   style="float: inherit; margin-right: 40%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
   />
</div>

 <!--Footer-->
 <div id="footer">



 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#footer").load("footer.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
  </div>
 <script>
 $(".parent").children("h2").click(function(){
    $(".parent").children("p", "img.first", "img.second", "img.third", "img.fourth", "img.fifth").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).siblings("p", "img.first", "img.second", "img.third", "img.fourth", "img.fifth").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".parent").children("img.first").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.first").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.second").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.second").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.third").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.third").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.fourth").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.fourth").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.fifth").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.fifth").css("display", "block");
});
 </script>
 </body
</html>
```

But this one and every other one I try won't:

```css
body {
  background-position: bottom;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
h1.first {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66CCFF;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 position: static;
 margin: 30px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66FF66;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}
img.first {
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.second{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.third{
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
img.fourth{
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
img.fifth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.eight{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.ninth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.tenth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.eleventh{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
p {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11.8pt;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\day1.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <title> Day One </title>
</head>
<body>
 <!--Navigation bar-->
 <div id="nav-placeholder">

 </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav1.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
 <!-- Heading-->

<h1 class='first' align='center'><big> Day One </h1></big>

<!-- Section One-->

<div class="parent">
   <h2 align='center'> Small Group </h2>
  <p align='center'> My small group leader was Jen Hall. She was amazing, she saved Nik and I seats so that we were able to meet our small group and made us feel welcome. Our small group were accommodating and likeable. In our small group was Dana, Cheryl, Mary, Leslie, Alexis, Nadine, Chelsea, Kimberly, Lauren, Renee and Lakesha. </p>
   <img class='first' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0088.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 1"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 17%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
   <img class='third' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0090.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 2"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
   <img class='second' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0089.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 3"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>

 <!--Section Two-->
 <div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> What Did We Do? </h2>
 <p> We started off with an opening session. In this session there was a video introducing a new country to the group made by the attendees from that country, and there were discussions about someone people had connected with the previous day as well as the timetable for the day. In the morning we had a session let by Jaime LaForgia and then it was lunch time! <br/> I didn't realise how much I was going to like American food. Turns out it is A LOT.</p>
 <img class='fourth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\14.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>   
 <img class='fifth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\42.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <img class='eight' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\68.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <img class='ninth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\69.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>
 <!--Section 3-->
<div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> International Group </h2>
 <p> In the afternoon we went to a different building to be part of the international group meet up. Firstly, we looked at and discussed a powerpoint led by Lance about SOS and how to improve the Discovery software and services in front of the CEO, Bill Goodwyn. While in the room we had to introduce ourselves; say our name, where we worked, discuss our school community and/or how we use Discovery software in our school. Except I didn't. I stayed quiet, sat back in my chair and took in everything everyone else was saying, listened and just did not introduce myself; because I don't enjoy big groups. Thankfully, Christine let me get away with this, saved me the embarrassment and let me stay in my comfort zone. </p>
</div>

<!--Section 4-->
 <div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> The DEN at Night... </h2>
 <p> At night, the DEN becomes a different place. It becomes less professional and more... personal and party-vibey. Alcohol is found and everyone becomes less tense, people relax, make friends, network in ways we can't during the day. During the DEN at Night I made friends with an awesome group of people, including Kelli, Heather and Kamala. These are my newest life-long friends.:)</p>
 <img class='tenth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\13.jpg"
  height="150px"
  width="250px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Friends and I"/>
 <img class='eleventh' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\72.jpg"
  height="250px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Friends and I"/>
 <p style="clear: both;"></p>
 </div>
 
 <!--Footer-->
 <div id="footer">

 </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#footer").load("footer.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
<script>
  $(".parent").children("h2").click(function(){
    $(".parent").children("p").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).siblings("p").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".parent").children("img.first", "img.second", "img.third").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.first", "img.second", "img.third").css("display", "block"); 
    $(".parent").children("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
$(".parent").children("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.tenth", "img.eleventh").css("display", "block");    
});
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using `jQuery` you will need to use the `.ready` event. This event is ran once the `DOM` is ready (Document Object Model).

So your script code should be

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".parent").children("h2").click(function(){
    $(".parent").children("p", "img.first", "img.second", "img.third", "img.fourth", "img.fifth").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).siblings("p", "img.first", "img.second", "img.third", "img.fourth", "img.fifth").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".parent").children("img.first").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.first").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.second").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.second").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.third").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.third").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.fourth").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.fourth").css("display", "block");
    $(".parent").children("img.fifth").css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings("img.fifth").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

What you should probably do is save this code into a `.js` file and reference that in your header like so

```
<script src="DisplayContents.js"></script>
```

The linking the script to your file you will need to provide its location just like your `img src` locations.

Also for `showing` and `hiding` elements why not try `.hide()` and `.show()` these are both jQuery functions.

Also if you press the `F12` key you will be given a browser console window. You can use this to help find any problems your page/site may have.

--- Update ---

jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vvof6s1r/

CSS

```
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-position: bottom;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

img.sixth {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

h1.first {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border: Dashed 3px;
  border-color: #66CCFF;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: static;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border: Dashed 3px;
  border-color: #66FF66;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

img.first {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

img.second {
  margin: auto;
}

img.third {
  margin: auto;
}

img.fourth {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img.fifth {
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">

</div>

<!--Finish NavBar-->

<!--Page Heading-->

<div id='heading'>
  <h1 class='first' align='center'>DENSI 2017 </h1>
</div>

<img class='sixth' src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" height="200px" width="250px" border="1px" position="center" alt="" />

<!--Section 1-->
<div class="parent">
  <h2 align='center' class="display-content-header"> What is it? </h2>
  <div class="display-content">
    <p align='center'> DENSI stands for Discovery Education Network Summer Institute. It is a week long residential professional development that helps educators learn, share and connect with other educators about good practice; integrating technology into the classroom
      and to give different perspectives on strategies to engage children. </p>
    <img class='second' src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="DEN Group Photo" height="150px" width="270px" border="1px" style="float: left; margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 3em;" />
    <img class='third' src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Discovery Logo" height="250px" width="180px" border="1px" style="float: right; margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom: 1em;" />
    <p style="clear: both;"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Section 2-->

<div class="parent">
  <h2 align='center' class="display-content-header"> Where was it held? </h2>
  <div class="display-content">
    <p align='center'> DENSI this year was held in San Diego at the University of California San Diego. In previous years it has been held in Washington, Chicago and Montana. San Diego has been a beautiful setting for DENSI this year (although there was no air con... and
      the wifi was a struggle...); once we had adjusted to the heat and the time difference we were well on our way to starting our once in a lifetime professional development experience!</p>
    <img class='fourth' src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" height="250px" width="180px" border="1px" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<!--Section 3-->

<div class="parent">
  <h2 align='center' class="display-content-header"> Who was there? </h2>
  <div class="display-content">
    <p class='third' align='center'> There were over 150 attendees at DENSI this year, several of which travelled from Egypt, England, UAE, Dubai, Haiti, Kuwait and China. Information on attendees can be found <span style="cursor:pointer"><a href="#"
 target="_blank">here.</a> </span>
      <p class='fourth' align='center'>
        Over the course of the week we had networked with the majority and had connected with many.</p>
      <img class='first' src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Internation Group Photo" height="180px" width="250px" border="1px" style="float: inherit; margin-right: 40%; margin-bottom: 5em;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(function() {

    $('.display-content').hide();

   $('.display-content-header').on('click', function() {
    $('.display-content').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.display-content').show();
   });
 });
```

I had to change your HTML in the jsfiddle example just so you can atleast see the images. I will quickly just run through the code.

First at DOM ready we just target all elements with the class name `display-content` and hide it (so you don't need to style the images out with CSS).

Then all we do is, if the user clicks any element with the class name `display-content-header` we first find all elements with the class name `display-content` and hide it (we do this so they can only ever have one parent expanded at a time). Then using the current click event we can move up a parent and then find its content and then just display it with `show`.

So the HTML for this script to work should look like this

```
<div>
    <h2 class="display-content-header">Header Title 2</h2>
    <div class="display-content">
        Here is some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be consistent. OP is already using the preferred `ready` elsewhere. `$(function(){ })`. Also since code block is after the elements it isn't relevant to problem

Comment: @charlietfl don't worry mate, just trying to help is all. jeez.

Comment: Okay so now the small group heading can be clicked but what did we do, the international group and den at night won't show..

Comment: @HayleyEvans I do apologize but I don't quite understand? Is the script working on both pages now? Or is the script not fully working?

Comment: @Canvas It's working on both but not fully, on the second (the one I posted) it is just opening one section, not the others when they are clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: @HayleyEvans you will need to make sure that both of your pages are structured the same. As your code is just target specific they will need to have the same element and class name

Comment: @Canvas As far as I can tell they are structured the same, I've looked over it about 10 times. How do I do the show and hide elements?

Comment: @HayleyEvans did you copy over the CSS, Javascript code and make changes to the HTML?

Comment: @Canvas YOU ARE A GENIUS THANK YOU

Comment: @HayleyEvans If the answer is correct make sure to click the tick next to the answer, and don't worry about glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing end of script tag please add `</script>` for second code or try below code.

```css
body {
  background-position: bottom;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
h1.first {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66CCFF;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 position: static;
 margin: 30px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 border: Dashed 3px;
 border-color: #66FF66;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}
img.first {
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.second{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.third{
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
img.fourth{
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
img.fifth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.eight{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.ninth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.tenth{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
img.eleventh{
   display: none;
   margin: auto;
}
p {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11.8pt;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\day1.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <title> Day One </title>
</head>
<body>
 <!--Navigation bar-->
 <div id="nav-placeholder">

 </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav1.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
 <!-- Heading-->

<h1 class='first' align='center'><big> Day One </h1></big>

<!-- Section One-->

<div class="parent">
   <h2 align='center'> Small Group </h2>
  <p align='center'> My small group leader was Jen Hall. She was amazing, she saved Nik and I seats so that we were able to meet our small group and made us feel welcome. Our small group were accommodating and likeable. In our small group was Dana, Cheryl, Mary, Leslie, Alexis, Nadine, Chelsea, Kimberly, Lauren, Renee and Lakesha. </p>
   <img class='first' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0088.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 1"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 17%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
   <img class='third' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0090.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 2"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
   <img class='second' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\IMG_0089.jpg" alt="Our Small Group 3"
  height="130px"
  width="200px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom:0.5em; margin-top: 1em;"
  />
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>

 <!--Section Two-->
 <div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> What Did We Do? </h2>
 <p> We started off with an opening session. In this session there was a video introducing a new country to the group made by the attendees from that country, and there were discussions about someone people had connected with the previous day as well as the timetable for the day. In the morning we had a session let by Jaime LaForgia and then it was lunch time! <br/> I didn't realise how much I was going to like American food. Turns out it is A LOT.</p>
 <img class='fourth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\14.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>   
 <img class='fifth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\42.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <img class='eight' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\68.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <img class='ninth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\69.jpg"
  height="200px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Food"/>
 <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>
 <!--Section 3-->
<div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> International Group </h2>
 <p> In the afternoon we went to a different building to be part of the international group meet up. Firstly, we looked at and discussed a powerpoint led by Lance about SOS and how to improve the Discovery software and services in front of the CEO, Bill Goodwyn. While in the room we had to introduce ourselves; say our name, where we worked, discuss our school community and/or how we use Discovery software in our school. Except I didn't. I stayed quiet, sat back in my chair and took in everything everyone else was saying, listened and just did not introduce myself; because I don't enjoy big groups. Thankfully, Christine let me get away with this, saved me the embarrassment and let me stay in my comfort zone. </p>
</div>

<!--Section 4-->
 <div id='parent'>
 <h2 align='center'> The DEN at Night... </h2>
 <p> At night, the DEN becomes a different place. It becomes less professional and more... personal and party-vibey. Alcohol is found and everyone becomes less tense, people relax, make friends, network in ways we can't during the day. During the DEN at Night I made friends with an awesome group of people, including Kelli, Heather and Kamala. These are my newest life-long friends.:)</p>
 <img class='tenth' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\13.jpg"
  height="150px"
  width="250px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Friends and I"/>
 <img class='eleventh' src="C:\Users\Hayley\Documents\Coding\DENSI\72.jpg"
  height="250px"
  width="150px"
  border="1px"
  style="float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-bottom: 5em;"
  alt="American Friends and I"/>
 <p style="clear: both;"></p>
 </div>
 
 <!--Footer-->
 <div id="footer">

 </div>

 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("#footer").load("footer.htm")
 ;
 });
 </script>
<script>
  $(".parent").children("h2").click(function(){
    $(".parent").children("p").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).siblings("p").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".parent").children("img.first", "img.second", "img.third").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.first", "img.second", "img.third").css("display", "block"); 
    $(".parent").children("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
$(".parent").children("img.fourth", "img.fifth", "img.eight", "img.ninth").css("display", "block");
    $(this).siblings("img.tenth", "img.eleventh").css("display", "block");    
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```